# Publish more WCF services at once

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, iis, service

I have multiple independent WCF services in my solution (15 projects) and I need to publish them many times during day. Currently I am publishing each service at the time. But is here any way I can select them and just publish them all at once? So I dont have to click on each and press "Publish" (also have keyboard shortcut, but it's still paint to do it separately)

Thank you for answers

Comment: Create wix installer to publish them all at once

Comment: I don't know if this does help me. I need to publish them to IIS. For instalation we use click once instalation.

Comment: You can create installer which will publish each site to iis - it's a common scenario. But as I said You will have to use WIX as clickonce doesn't have all required features

Comment: Just use powershell http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell